# Story identification: live action sci-fi series about aliens related to a comet and gold hexagons as the symbol

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I have been looking for this series on google for several tries, each time with zero results.

All I have is that the series had a female protagonist. She lives in a small town, and a comet comes by and hangs in the sky for a while. She discovers the town has a strange cult/aliens that are using hexatonal gold pieces to power a machine.
I can vaguely recall an early episode being about a different girl being into archeology, and the protagonist is a dick and steals a bracelet from her?

The stupid thing is that this used to show on KinderNet which is a absolved dutch channel, which had a knack for finding extremely obscure television shows(the secret of treasure island and Argaï: the profecy amonst them)

Comment: [This translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&u=http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindernet&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dkindernet%2Bseries%26client%3Dfirefox-a%26hs%3D5lO%26rls%3Dorg.mozilla:en-US:official%26channel%3Drcs%26biw%3D1366%26bih%3D656) of a wiki site has a pretty good list. Hopefully it can help.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Night of the Red Hunter - Pic 01]

[**Night of the Red Hunter**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0224930/)

You're right, it is an obscure show. But there have been others looking for it in the past :-) Anyway, here's a synopsis:

> Night of the Red Hunter is a 1989 mystery series aired on Television
>   New Zealand about two runaway children named Peter and Maggie. The two
>   bump into each other in Piper Valley, a small countryside town. A crazy
>   man chases them into a graveyard where they choose to hide.

They stumble upon the "treasure":

> The kids accidentally trigger a secret opening in the graveyard and
>   fall. They find themselves in a room filled with intense light.
>   Looking around, they discover strange equipment and millions of
>   dollars in gold artifacts. But before they can explore further, they
>   faint.

[image: Night of the Red Hunter - Pic 02]

How these kids meet the aliens:

> The children wake up the next day with no memory of the previous night
>   in the farmhouse of the Pipers, a seemingly friendly yet somehow
>   sinister family. They turn out to be a race of benevolent aliens,
>   stranded on Earth until they get their ship repaired.

More about the mysterious cache of gold:

> The aliens are allergic to the gold which they require to power their
>   ship, mentioning in passing how the Earth is poisoned by the toxic
>   effects of our own fuels.

[image: Night of the Red Hunter - Pic 04]

A brief mention of the comet you brought up in your post:

> Meantime, the comet Nimrod is about to pass close to Earth, but Nimrod
>   is really a planet-killing weapon with the power of a thousand nuclear
>   weapons, and the Earth is doomed unless the scrappy runaways cooperate
>   with each other and a slightly older alien child.

<sup>*~ Edited from [tv.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/night-of-the-red-hunter/) and [Time Capsule (by J. P. Harris)](http://tinyurl.com/myswz34)*</sup>

Find out more about the show and watch a few clips [here](http://www.nzonscreen.com/title/night-of-the-red-hunter-1989/series).